# How to combine two specific cells using a comma separation in R

Tags: r, concatenation, cell, paste

I have the following data set

[image: Data that needs combining]

I'd like it such that cell [2,6] retains its current content with the addition of the cell below it, separated by a "," I have found `paste()` functions for concatenating columns into new columns but can't find an answer for specific cell combinations. Any help appreciated.

[image: Example]

For example, I'd like the highlighted cell in the above to read `John, Mary`

Comment: Please provide reproducible example using dput with input and required output as the question is vague.

Comment: I've edited the post for a bit more clarity

Comment: Here's a way of how you can make a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `library(dplyr); data %>% group_by(Type) %>% summarise(name = paste0(Name, collapse = ', '))` ?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way on how you can paste values with the values in below row.

```
# Loading required libraries
library(dplyr)

# Creating sample data
example <- data.frame(Type = c("Director", NA_character_),
                      Name = c("John", "Mary"))

example %>%
  # Get value of the below row
  mutate(new_col = lead(Name, 1),
         # If Type is director then paste names else null
         new_col = ifelse(Type == "Director", paste(Name, new_col, sep = ", "), NA_character_))
```

Comment: In the end I used the following:

```df_AEC <- AEC_data_global_front %>%
  add_row(Type = "Directors", Details = "CONCAT")```

```df_AEC[8,2] = paste(df_AEC[6,2], df_AEC[7,2], sep = ", ")
AEC_contacts <- df_AEC[-c(6, 7), ]```

Creating a new column then creating a concatenated cell and deleting the previous column.